# Tasker recognize when headphones are in and something starts playing

Tags: tasker

I have this issue with my phone when I put in my bluetooth headphones and start playing something, it switches to the "cast" volume mutes my music, so I have to raise my volume every time that I put in my headphones. I already have tasker turn up my volume when my headphones are in, but it isn't until the music starts playing that it switches to "cast" volume instead of bluetooth. Can I have a Tasker action happen when my headphones are in AND music starts?

Answer (score 0):

You can either use the plugin "[Tasker Is Music Playing](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=se.harenamons.ismusicplaying&hl=de)", for one dollar, or try the "[Media Utilities](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.batescorp.notificationmediacontrols.alpha&hl=de)" for free, which interface with Tasker but might or might not work with your specific media player.